# Do Liquid templares support the concept of documents?

Tags: jekyll, liquid

I am using the Liquid templating language with Jekyll. I need to be able to define Liquid variables that have a document scope where a document may contain several pages. Is this possible?

Comment: I am not sure if I get what you want. Do you refer to a [layout](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/step-by-step/04-layouts/) for a set of pages?

Comment: I would like a document to be made up of a number of pages. If one could then define variables at the document level, they would be accessible to all pages in the document. Also, a given page could be a member of more than one document so page reuse would be maximized.

Comment: Could [front matter defaults](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/front-matter-defaults/) help you? If not, share some (pseudo) code.